# Bootstrap popover not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an element on the page as follows:

```
<a data-ajaxload="/League/PointBreakdown/228583" href="#228583" class="point-breakdown" data-original-title="" title="">-</a>
```

I am calling the popover as below, the content returned is HTML and everything works OK by getting a small amount of HTML from the server.  There are many of these links on the page but I am having the issue that I cannot click the same link twice. I can see the popover flashes and closes immediately.  I only want one on the page at any one time, i.e remove one when another is open.

```
$('*[data-ajaxload]').bind('click', function () {


        if ($(this).parent().children('.popover').length > 0) {
            return;
        }

        ShowSpinner($(this).parents('table'));

        try {
            $('.popover').remove();

            var e = $(this);

            $.get(e.data('ajaxload'), function (d) {

                e.popover({ content: d, html: true }).popover('show');

                HideSpinner();
            });

        }
        catch (ex) {

            HideSpinner();
            $('.popover').remove();
        }
    });
// pass in element to move the mask
function ShowSpinner(elem) {

    if (typeof (elem) != 'undefined' || elem != 'undefined') {

        // move the mask
        $('#mask').appendTo($(elem));
    }

    $('#mask').show();

}
function HideSpinner() {

    $('#mask').appendTo($('body'));
    $('#mask').hide();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply I changed the code to the below:

```
$('*[data-ajaxload]').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $('.popover').remove();

        var link = $(this).attr('data-ajaxload');
        var content = "";
        $.ajax({
            cache: true,
            type: 'post',
            async: false,
            url: link,
            success: function (result) {

                content = result;
            }

        }); // end ajax

        $(this).popover(
            {
                html: true,
                content: content
            }).popover('show');

    });
```